# Calculate the mass of K

Tags: integration

The curves $y = \cos x$ , $y = \sin 2 x$ and the y-axis defines the flat figure K.

K's density in the point (x,y) is $\cos x$ mass units per area unit.

Calculate the mass of K.

I stated the density as

$$ \rho = \frac{A}{\cos x} $$
and

$$ A = \int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{\cos x - \sin 2x }{\cos x}dx = \int_0^{\pi/6} \frac{\cos x - 2\sin x\cos x }{\cos x}dx = \int_0^{\pi/6} 1 - 2 \sin xdx = \frac{\pi}{6} + \sqrt{3} -2 $$

However the correct answer should be $\frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8} - \frac{2}{3}$

Where did I get wrong?

Comment: the question doesn't mention the limit?

Comment: The limits are where the two curves intersect. And that's in 0 and $\pi / 6$. K is the area between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$$dm=\rho dA$$
$$\rho=\cos x\text{ mass/area }$$
$$dA=(\cos x-\sin 2x)\times dx$$
$$dm=\cos x(\cos x-\sin 2x)dx$$
$$M=\int dm
=\int_0^{\pi/6} \cos x(\cos x-\sin 2x)dx\\
=\int_0^{\pi/6} \left(\frac12 (-\sin(x)-\sin(3 x)+\cos(2 x)+1)\right)dx\\
=\frac12\left[\cos x+\frac13\cos 3x+\frac12\sin 2x+x\right]_0^{\pi/6}\\
=\frac12\left[\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2-1\right)+\frac13(0-1)+\frac12\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2-0\right)+\left(\frac{\pi}6-0\right)\right]\\
=\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{3\sqrt3}8-\frac23$$

Comment: Very nice answer. However how did you go from $\cos x (\cos x - \sin 2x )$ to $ (\frac{1}{2} (-\sin x ...$?

Comment: cos2x=2cos^2x-1;2sin2xcosx=sin3x+sinx;

Answer (score 0):

If I read the question correctly, $\sigma = \cos x$, so 'mass' is an integral of the density over the area:

$$\begin{align}A 
& = \int\limits_{x=0}^{\pi/6}\int\limits_{y=\sin 2x}^{\cos x}\sigma\,dy\,dx \\
& = \int\limits_{x=0}^{\pi/6}\int\limits_{y=\sin 2x}^{\cos x}\cos x\,dy\,dx \\
& = \int\limits_{x=0}^{\pi/6}\cos x\int\limits_{y=\sin 2x}^{\cos x}\,dy\,dx \\
& = \int\limits_{x=0}^{\pi/6}\cos x (\cos x - \sin 2x)\,dx \\
& = \ldots
\end{align}$$